# Store options price in laravel shopping cart with session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I work with laravel 5.5 and I have cart which stores data in session so far everything works just fine and now I want add option such as `color` `size` etc. which each of them has different price and this price should be add to my cart.

The problem is I can't get their prices in my cart.

here is my session store/remove/etc in my `Cart` model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'carts';

      public $items = null;
      public $totalQty = 0;
      public $totalPrice = 0;
      public function __construct($oldCart)
      {
          if ($oldCart) {
              $this->items = $oldCart->items;
              $this->totalQty = $oldCart->totalQty;
              $this->totalPrice = $oldCart->totalPrice;
          }
      }
      public function add($item, $id) {
          $storedItem = ['qty' => 0, 'price' => $item->price, 'item' => $item];
          if ($this->items) {
              if (array_key_exists($id, $this->items)) {
                  $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
              }
          }
          $storedItem['qty']++;
          $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
          $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
          $this->totalQty++;
          $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
      }

      public function reduceByOne($id)
      {
          $this->items[$id]['qty']--;
          $this->items[$id]['price'] -= $this->items[$id]['item']['price'];
          $this->totalQty--;
          $this->totalPrice -= $this->items[$id]['item']['price'];

          if ($this->items[$id]['qty'] <= 0) {
            unset($this->items[$id]);
          }
      }

      public function increaseByOne($id)
      {
          $this->items[$id]['qty']++;
          $this->items[$id]['price'] += $this->items[$id]['item']['price'];
          $this->totalQty++;
          $this->totalPrice += $this->items[$id]['item']['price'];
      }

      public function removeItem($id)
      {
          $this->totalQty -= $this->items[$id]['qty'];
          $this->totalPrice -= $this->items[$id]['price'];
          unset($this->items[$id]);
      }

    protected $fillable = [
        'coupon_code',
    ];

    public function product(){
       return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

this is my `route`

```
Route::resource('/cart', 'CartController', ['except' => ['show', 'create']]);
```

Here is my `CartController`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Cart;
use App\Product;
use Auth;
use Session;
use App\User;

class CartController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function AddToCart(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
        $cart->add($product, $product->id);
        $request->session()->put('cart', $cart);
        Session::flash('flash_message', 'Item added to your cart successfully.');
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function reduceByOne($id)
    {
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->reduceByOne($id);
      Session::put('cart', $cart);
      return redirect()->back();
    }
    public function increaseByOne($id)
    {
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->increaseByOne($id);
      Session::put('cart', $cart);
      return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function removeItem($id)
    {
      $oldCart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $cart->removeItem($id);

      if (count($cart->items) > 0) {
        Session::put('cart', $cart);
      } else {
        Session::forget('cart');
      }


      return redirect()->back();
    }

    public function index()
    {
      $user = Auth()->user();
      if (!Session::has('cart')) {
        return view('frontend.cart');
      }
      $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
      $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
      $total = $cart->totalPrice;
      return view('frontend.cart', ['products' => $cart->items, 'totalPrice' => $cart->totalPrice, 'user' => $user, 'total' => $total]);
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And this is my `Options` code in blade:

```
<div class="options">
<h3>options:</h3>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tbody>
@foreach($product->suboptions as $option)
<tr>
<th style="width:150px;">{{ $option->option->title }}</th>
<td class="text-left">
{{ Form::checkbox('option', '$option->id') }}{{$option->title}}-{{$option->price}}
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Its not clear to me what the problem is.  Are you saying you want to add more properties to the items that would effect the price?  Wouldn't that mean you should treat each item+color+size etc combination as its own item type?

Comment: Exactly that is what I'm saying, + my options are dynamic which means that I don't know later what options will be, could be color, size could be other things that's depend on website owner what he/she wants to add as option. The question is: what codes should I add to my existence code in cart model to get options prices?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips any idea?

Comment: What does your cart table look like? Is there an items "hasMany" relationship, or is the list of items stored in a JSON column?  Will all items have the same extra cost for the added properties?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips I don't have cart table! I save in session and not database. and this is in my `product model`  `public function cart(){
     return $this->hasMany(Cart::class);
  }`

Comment: @ChrisPhillips this is my cart fron-end view:  https://imgur.com/a/bVt1c

Comment: Well if you don't store this info in the database, then it doesn't need to be an Eloquent model.  I'm trying to figure out how you want to keep track of the item data. Once there is a final checkout/sale of the cart, how do you keep track of the information?  Do you write it to an 'ORDER' table or something similar?  Ideally the Cart data should be setup similarly to how you will finally be saving it.